# Pass argument from script to gulp task

Tags: npm, gulp, arguments, package.json, npm-scripts

I have `package.json` scripts with the following structure:

```json
"scripts": {
    "watch:build": "tsc --watch",
    "watch:server": "nodemon ./src/app.js --watch 'app'",
    "build": "tsc && gulp do_something",
    "start": "npm-run-all clean build --parallel watch:build", 
    "watch:server --print-label"
}
```

I would like to start the application as `npm run start with_argument` 
and pass it to `build` script, to perform actions in the gulp task based on that argument.

I read a lot of tutorial and how to articles, but without result. It is possible somehow to pass argument from one script to another(which starts a gulp task).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm-run-all` provides a its own custom mechanism for handling arguments by utilizing placeholders in npm-scripts, as stated in the *Argument Placeholders* section of its documentation found [here](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/HEAD/docs/npm-run-all.md#argument-placeholders).

#### npm-script:

Given your current npm-script named `start` you'll need to redefine it as follows:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "start": "npm-run-all clean \"build -- {@}\" --parallel watch:build --"
  ...
}
```

**Notes:**

- `-- {@}` must be added after `build`.**<sup>1</sup>**
- `build -- {@}` must be wrapped in escaped double quotes `\"...\"`
- `--` must also be added after last script invocation, namely: `watch:build`

---

#### gulpfile.js

To obtain the arguments passed via the CLI inside your *gulpfile.js* you''ll need to utilize nodes [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

For the purpose of demonstration lets say our *gulpfile.js* is as follows:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var args = process.argv.splice(3, process.argv.length - 3);

gulp.task('doSomething', function() {

  // For testing purposes...
  if (args.indexOf('--foo') > -1) {
    console.log('--foo was passed via the CLI.')
  }

  if (args.indexOf('--quux') > -1) {
    console.log('--quux was passed via the CLI.')
  }
});
```

**Notes:**

1. The first three items in nodes `process.argv` are:

   - The path to the executable running the JavaScript file.
   - The path of the JavaScript file being executed.
   - The name of the gulp task, i.e. `doSomething`
2. However, we're only interested in the elements from the fourth item in the array onwards - as these will be the arguments passed via the CLI. The line which reads:

   ```js
   var args = process.argv.splice(3, process.argv.length - 3);
   ```

   creates an `args` variable and assigns an Array containing each argument passed via the CLI, i.e. we omit the first three aforementioned items in point 1 above using the Arrays [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

---

#### Running your `start` script:

You invoke your start script via your CLI as follows:

```
$ npm start -- --foo --quux
```

**Note** You must provide the `--` which precedes `npm start` before providing your own arguments.

---

#### Output:

- Using the contrived `gulpfile.js` above, in combination with your current scripts defined in your *package.json*, and of course the necessary changes made to your `start` script. When you run:

  ```
  $ npm start -- --foo --quux
  ```

  you will see the following printed to the console:

  > `--foo was passed via the CLI.`
  >
  > `--quux was passed via the CLI.`
- Running:

  ```
  $ npm start -- --quux
  ```

  you will see just the following printed to the console:

  > `--quux was passed via the CLI.`
- And of course, running:

  ```
  $ npm start
  ```

  Does not print either of the messages defined in *gulpfile.js*.

---

**<sub>Footnotes:</sub>**

**1** <sub>`-- {@}` can be replaced with `-- {1}` if you only intend to pass one argument. However, `-- {@}` handles multiple arguments, so it's fine to use it for one argument too.</sub>

---